# Send facebook request from google endpoints

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-graph-api, google-cloud-endpoints

I've Googled around, though I can't seem to find an answer.

Currently using Google endpoints with android studio.

I'm looking to send a Facebook request via my backend server (java). (Assume i have the access token).

How can I achieve this?

Comment: If you have no further comments or problems, please mark my answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

please include code and examples of what you have tried to do already. Your questions needs to be specific about a programming issue. Right now it is too general.

Though I'm not 100% about this, I believe facebook doesnt allow this to work. Access tokens should not be shared. And servers shouldnt be able to pretend to be other clients.

Any allowed uses of the fb API will be done using the server's own access token, and not any other.